# Rails request.url is fetching url as http when it's actually https

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added `<link rel="canonical" href="<%= request.url %>" />` to all the landing erb pages. The platform is actually `HTTPS` secure completely.

But this canonical tag is fetching `http` url like below:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/search?category_id=metal-processing-and-machine-tool" />
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

You should get `request.protocol` as well

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<%= request.protocol %><%= request.url %>" />
```